# How can I debug my react library in my application?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I created my own react library using npm which I use constancy in my main code. Is there any easy way to debug my package except debugging my compiled js in the chrome debugger?

I already used npm link, but I still can't see the original react components in the debugger which makes the debugging impossible.

thanks:)